# Why rasters of the same projections don't overlap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, overlapping-features

I tried to search for existing questions to see if I could find answers, but I didn't.  I have two rasters as shown.  The raster with gray borders is not titling the right way.  It should have tilted and overlapped with the raster with red border.
[image]
Both rasters were projected the same way, figure attached.
[image]
What caused the non-overlap of the two rasters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the set coordinate system is incorrect.

Install a plugin such as QuickMapServices to load OSM and make sure it is located correctly.

The coordinate system of the raster that is not positioned correctly may not be the set coordinate system.

It is most accurate to ask the supplier who provided the original data for the coordinate system.

If it is not possible, set the correct coordinate system in your experience by changing the setting to a commonly used coordinate system.

Comment: I used ENVI and they overlap! I am not sure why they won't overlap on ArcGIS or QGIS.  But thank you for the plugin suggestion.